# How do I write jQuery(function($) {...} in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

In [this tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms) it includes the code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // do stuff ...
});
```

How do I write this in CoffeeScript?  `jQuery($) ->` isn't right, but I can't work out what is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a space after `jQuery` to make an anonymous function with `$` as its only argument:

```
jQuery ($) ->
    foo();
```

And the result:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  return foo();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If I remember right, just like this: `$ ->`

Comment: This potentially works too, but it isn't the same as the code the OP posted since he make have jQuery in noConflict mode.